# Calculate number images in a row to fit container while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, logic, masonry

I want to create a masonry horizontal layout like this [library](https://naver.github.io/egjs-infinitegrid/#JustifiedLayout). It contain collection of images with different height and width each other.

The layout can have one or more rows, as long as it meets this criteria:

- Row width fit to the masonry container width
- Row can have different height each other
- Row have restriction minimum and maximum height value

A row can have one or more columns (the image), as long as it meets this criteria:

- Image keep their aspect ratio
- Image in same row must be same height
  Has fixed gap width each image

Here the illustration:

[image]

Here is the more real example of Canva images tab:

[image]

I'm starting to code this using JavaScript (React Hook), but I'm stuck with the logic.

Imagine there is lot of images with different dimension, that has inline-block display style. My current logic to that case is:

- Get images width and height for keeping aspect ratio Modify images
- height with minimum row height value, while keeping aspect ratio
- Now all images has same height, but row width isn't fit to container
- *And then i'm stuck on this*

Part of current progress

```
function Masonry({ minHeight, children }) {
  const _originalDimension = [];
  const _tempDimension = [];

  children.forEach(({ props: { height, width } }) => {
    const newWidth = (width / height) * minHeight;
    const newHeight = minHeight;

    _originalDimension.push({ height, width });
    _tempDimension.push({ height: newHeight, width: newWidth });
  });

  const { container } = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={container}>
      {children.map((child, i) =>
        cloneElement(child, { key: i, ..._tempDimension[i] })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can't reach how possibly a row can fit to the container width and how can a row calculate number of images to fit minimum or maximum row height.

Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code/logic you have tried for a better understanding

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404026/smart-alignment-layout-of-multiple-images-on-page/21417228#21417228) to an older question is useful to you. See it at work [here](http://martin-oehm.de/data/layout.html).